# "Error: Root should be either UIViewController or UIView" Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-components, angular-module

So I'm trying to create a component inside of a new module, and then use it inside 'app', but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Root should be either UIViewController or UIView
```

This is my sample.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from 'nativescript-angular/common';
import { SampleComponent } from './sample/sample.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SampleComponent], // <= this is the component I want to use
  exports: [SampleComponent],
  imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class SampleModule { }
```

Then my sampleComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ns-sample',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css'],
  moduleId: module.id,
})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Then inside of my app I'm importing the module like this:

```
imports: [
    // ... other modules
    SampleModule,
],
```

The error messages fires when I try to use my SampleComponent selector inside of app.component.html like this:

```
<ns-sample></ns-sample>
```

I've been looking around, but I keep finding mistakes where people forgot to export the module itself. I'm already doing that, so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

So the question is how do I use a component declared in a different module inside of app?

Thanks in advance guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a custom component wrap it with a ContentView / StackLayout when you are placing it as root element.

```
<StackLayout>
  <ns-sample></ns-sample>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Oh man! that worked! Thanks so much. I was going crazy trying to figure it out

Comment: Also I was following a tutorial, but it's kind of outdated. Do you know any that would be helpful? or any tools to help me get started on nativescript?