# NativeScript V8 BottomNavigation error: "Root should be either UIViewController or UIView"

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm reading through the official document for NativeScript, and come across this playground example code related to "BottomNavigation".

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=U4Rmr9&v=2

I tried to replicate the code using:

- tns version "8.0.2"
- angular cli version "12.0.5"

And I this error when running "tns run ios", stating that "Root should be either UIViewController or UIView".

I tried google for solutions, come across solution like this: 
["Error: Root should be either UIViewController or UIView" Nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688874/error-root-should-be-either-uiviewcontroller-or-uiview-nativescript)

I tried wrapping the entire "BottomNavigation" or just the "page-router-outlet", but still get weird results.

Can anybody help me with this?
I've created a git repo to simulate the issue:
https://github.com/HidePoSy/TestNativeScriptBottomNavigation.git

All that's need to run it is run "tns run ios".

Thanks.